# Sprite image moves down when hovering over

Tags: css, sprite

I am using a sprite to change the color of an image on its hover status, though when I hover over the image it moves down slightly and changes color. I have created a   [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/k4uPx/2/) to replicate the problem.

I am probably using the sprite incorrectly? I'm unsure as it is my first time playing with them.

```
.ratings ul li {
width:18px;
height:18px;
background:url(star.png) 145px 102px;
}

.ratings ul li:hover{
width:18px;
height:18px;
background:url(star.png) 145px 86px;
 }
```

I am using this image:    [image]

Can anyone can point out my mistakes?

Comment: The image in your demo fails to load. Dropbox seems to return a 403.

Comment: images from you dropbox are not available for anonymous users

Comment: ok ill sort now, thanks for letting me know

Comment: can i put image in public dropbox folder?

Comment: By your description I'd say that you just simply no use the correct offset for your sprite. I don't have the image so can't see it, but try to change the value of your y value in your hover if you haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Cause**

The sprite is not configured correctly. At least one of the `background-position` values should be either zero or negative in your example.

The technique of [CSS sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) depends on negative `background-position` values to change the *area* within the image used as the element's background. In contrast, positive (i.e. greater than zero) `background-position` values actually change the *position* of the background image in the element.

**Solution**

```
background:url(star.png) 0 0;

background:url(star.png) 0 -18px;
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k4uPx/3/)**

**Note about the image**

Also note that your current sprite is `34px` high, while it seems each star is only `16px` high. This means there's a `2px` gap between the two stars, so the second `background-position` is `-18px` and not `-16px`.

Comment: thank you, but the star still moves on hover? Im using chrome if that makes a difference?

Comment: @Richlewis True. This is because the star images are not equal. The first one is just 1px higher than the first. Just noticed that. When you positioned the second in your graphic editor, it probably moved a pixel down.

Comment: because of the 2px gap? should i edit image and remove this gap?

Comment: Yes, move your second star 2 pixels up and make sure it's exactly 16px like the first. Then crop the image to make it 32px.

Answer (score 3):

```
.ratings ul li {
  width:16px; /* redefine your image offset */
  height:16px; 
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5T0M.png) no-repeat;
}
.ratings ul li:hover {
  background-position: 0 -18px;
}
```

You do not need to define `width` and `height` which you had already on `:hover` state. You should find informative guidance about css sprires on [this](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) site

Answer (score 2):

First: you should use a `16px` "box" (width/height) for your star not 18 because your star has a width of `16px`.

Then change your offset correctly, you will have less problem.

Comment: On a side note, you should carefully design your sprite image, respecting some kind of grid, position your images correctly (1px matters) and make it easier for you to know the offset you need to apply.